# What reference do I need to use MAPI to send mail from VBA?

Tags: mapi

I'm trying to send a report to people through Access Database (SendObject VB code). It has been successul until we rollout Microsoft Outlook 2010 last November.

Since the upgrade, we can't send the report out anymore. We are getting a compile Error message: "User-defined type not defined" with "MAPISession As MAPI.Session" HIGHLIGHTED in blue.

[image: error]

I'm guessing this might be a reference issue, so I went in Tools\References then click on "Messenger API Type Library" hoping it will help, but it didn't help. Still getting the same error message.

Could anyone advise me on what to do next?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is CDO 1.21.
It is an optional component in Outlook 2007. Outlook 2010 does not install it at all.
You can download it from http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=3671
Keep in mind that it only comes in 32 bit and has not been updated (functionality wise) for the last 10 years.
Other alternatives are Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi only) or [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author), in particular its [RDO](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdo_introduction.htm) family of objects - [Redemption.RDOSession](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm) is very similar to `MAPI.Session` in CDO 1.21.

Comment: I tried to install the CDO package but couldn't. It says I have to have Outlook 2007 also installed on my computer before I can install the CDO. I'm sure the RDO would work, but it's not an open source. Thank you again.

Comment: Are you using the 64 bit version of Outlook 2010?

Comment: We have the 32 bit version of Outlook 2010

Comment: You can try Redemption (http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/)- it works in all versions of outlook and is available in both 32 and 64 bit.